# calculating success which depends on a different scenarios of a previous success problem

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

A group of 20 hunters there are 4 excellent, 10 good and 6 mediocre ones.
The probability for an excellent hunter to shoot a target is 0.9, for good one - 0.7 and for mediocre - 0.5. I am asked what is the probability that a target is hit, and what is the probability that if 2 hunters shoot one after another on two different targets, there are two hits on the respective targets.

My solution:
I have named the groups of hunters $H_1, H_2$ and $H_3$ and the event of hitting a target - $A$. Using the formula for total probability I have calculated that:
$$
P(A)=\sum_{i=1}^3P(H_i)P(A|H_i)=\frac{4}{20}0.9+\frac{10}{20}0.7+\frac{6}{20}0.5=0.68
$$

Now for the second condition of the problem, I'm not so sure. My idea is the following:

Assuming the first target has been hit, there are 3 cases

1. being hit by someone of group $H_1$
2. being hit by someone of group $H_2$
3. being hit by someone of group $H_3$

So it looks to me I have to calculate the probabilities of all the different scenarios for a target being hit by the first, and then being hit by a second hunter who can be chosen dependently on the choosing of the first hunter (so there will be $-1$ hunters from one of the groups and from the total pack).

Is my logic correct or am I complicating things? How do I proceed with the second condition of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach for the first problem is correct. For the second problem I`m not sure if I understand you right. Therefore I show you how I would solve the problem. Firstly I would calculate the probabilities that two hunters are choosen from one (two) specific group(s).

$P(H_1,H_1)=\frac{4}{20}\cdot \frac{3}{19}, \  $ $P(H_1,H_2)=2\cdot \frac{4}{20}\cdot \frac{10}{19}\ $, $P(H_1,H_3)=2\cdot \frac{4}{20}\cdot \frac{6}{19}$,

$P(H_2,H_2)= \frac{10}{20}\cdot \frac{9}{19}\ $, $P(H_2,H_3)=2\cdot  \frac{10}{20}\cdot \frac{6}{19}\ $, $P(H_3,H_3)= \frac{6}{20}\cdot \frac{5}{19}$

Let $P(S_i,S_j|H_i,H_j)$ denote the probability that the two radomly choosen hunters from group $i$ and $j$ are successful. Then the asked probability is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{3} \sum_{j=i}^{3} P(S_i,S_j|H_i,H_j)\cdot P(H_i,H_j)$$

It is comprehensible and can you calculate the values for all  $P(S_i,S_j|H_i,H_j)$ ?

Comment: So it's still the formula for total probability where the hypotheses are $(H_i,H_j)$ forming the collectively exhaustive group of events and the conditional probability is defined by the event $S_i \cap S_j|H_i \cap H_j$.

Comment: You´re right it is the formula of the total probability.

Comment: Isn't the $P(S_i,S_j|H_i,H_j)$ just P(S_i|H_i)\times P(S_j|H_j) since the event of choosing one hunter is independent of the choosing of the second?

Comment: The probabilities of choosing are not independent, but the probablities of success are  indpendent from each other. You are right that $P(S_i,S_j|H_i,H_j)=P(S_i|H_i)\cdot P(S_j|H_j)$

Comment: To be more precise: The probability that a hunter from a certain group has success is independent from the probability that another hunter has success from the same or from another group. This is exactly what the equation says.